# How to create CNN structure which is depend on the number of input images with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am building a CNN structure which is able to take multiple images as input. The number of inputs is varying —- for example it can be 3 or 4 or any other number ideally.

Here is what I want:

When input 3 images, there will be 3 streams of vgg16 which share the same weights.

When input 4 images, there will be 4 streams of vgg16 which share the same weights.

In conclusion, the network structure can only be define after I feed data during training/testing. How can I do it with tensorflow?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be very helpful to give an example of what you have tried already and how it didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Are you talking about "batches"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example of a [TensorFlow placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder) :

```
x_train_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 256, 256, 3])
```

In the above placeholder `None` is used for the size of the 1st dimension which allows us to pass a variable number of input tensors (images) of size `(256, 256, 3)` as input to the CNN model without explicitly specifying/hard-coding these values.

Consider, we input a batch of images `x_train_batch` which is of dimensions `[4, 256, 256, 3]` in which the first dimension is 4 indicating we're passing a *batch* of 4 images to the model (this could be modified to 3 according to your problem description). Now, we could pass `x_train_batch` to the placeholder `x_train_placeholder` above using the below code of code:

```
_, loss_train = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x_train_placeholder: x_train_batch})
```

where `loss` is the definition of the cost function we're using to optimize our network. Notice that since we're not hard-coding the value of the first dimension of `x_train_batch` anywhere, this allows us to pass a variable number of images to the tensorflow placeholder during training or testing.